# If requests are asynchronous, why does reducing the number of http requests a page needs to load improve performance?

Tags: performance, http

I've been pouring over a few web page performance articles which all explain that reducing the number of http requests needed to load a page will reduce the total time it takes to load. I can't quite understand why it would though if http requests are asynchronous and happen in parallel.

One article I read seemed to let on that browsers deliberately limit the number of requests that they make to a single hostname, which I'm guessing has something to do with throttling, but I haven't found anything to confirm.

My intuition suggests that constructing the http requests must take some time on the client, and so though wait times are asynchronous, the construction of each request takes some small amount of time that becomes significant as the number of requests increases. But this is just a hunch.

Can anyone explain why performance increases with fewer http requests?

Answer (score 2):

Each HTTP request/response has a huge overhead. Not only is there a header block for both the request and the response, but there is also various handshake and headers on the tcp/ip layer, that underlines the http protocol.

If you're curious, I suggest that you install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and use it to inspect what kind of network traffic goes over the wire, then you visit a typical web site. It's quite a lot.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then this picture basically explains whats going on, right? (ignoring the titles) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/HTTP_persistent_connection.svg

Comment: That's part of it yes. But there is also the headers, which apply to each request.

Answer (score 1):

Every request/response pair contains http header data that has to be generated, transported and processed from client to server and vice versa. If you reduce the number of requests needed to load a page you reduce this overhead.

Additionally many browsers throttle the number of concurrent requests send out to the same host. See f.x. the network.http.pipelining.maxrequests and network.http.max-connections-per-server config parameters for FireFox. While a browser issues more requests to load your page, it will pipeline these requests and possibly connect more TCP streams to your host. Establishing a connection requires to wait for the three way handshake roundtrip and page load time will increase even more.

A real life example: Send out 5 people to get you a cup of coffee with milk,sugar and a spoon out of a tiny kitchen. Try that again with only one person.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is *synchronous* - you can use techniques such as AJAX to make a web *application* asynchronous, i.e. you can make HTTP requests asynchronously *to your page*; however, once you issue a HTTP request, you sit and wait for a response.

Comment: Right-- That doesn't explain however why a page that requires 10 10KB files loads slower than a page that requires 1 100KB file though. In theory, the first case should load faster (since the total time for the page to load should be the time it takes for the longest request to finish).

Comment: @CeasarBautista - The extra overhead from the HTTP protocol to negotiate and transfer data for each request increases the load on the server as well as the amount of data to transfer as compared to reducing the number of requests. Also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining

Comment: You forget that sending the request and sending the response are costly operations.

Comment: @CeasarBautista There's also the fact that the overhead for the requests is probably greater than the cost of the request itself.

Comment: HTTP 1.1, which is very common nowadays, allows you to send out more than one request at a time without waiting for the response. A modern browser uses that together with multiple connections to the same host and an event driven programming model to use HTTP as if it would be a asynchronous protocol.